# What is the usage of set-user-ID of a program file?

Tags: files, process, executable, uid

From APUE

> When we execute a program ﬁle, the effective user ID of the process is
>   usually the real user ID. However, we can also set the set-user-ID bit in the ﬁle’s
>   mode word (`st_mode`) that says, ‘‘When this ﬁle is executed, set the
>   effective user ID of the process to be the owner of the ﬁle
>   (`st_uid`).’’
>
> For example, if the owner of the ﬁle is the superuser and if the ﬁle’s
>   set-user-ID bit is set, then **while that program ﬁle is running as a
>   process, it has superuser privileges**. **This happens regardless of the
>   real user ID of the process that executes the ﬁle**. As an example, the
>   UNIX System program that allows anyone to change his or her password,
>   `passwd`(1), is a set-user-ID program.  This is required so that the
>   program can write the new password to the password ﬁle, typically
>   either `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`, ﬁles that should be writable only
>   by the superuser. Because a process that is running set-user-ID  to 
>   some  other  user  usually  assumes  extra  permissions,  it  must  be
>   written carefully.

Assume the set-user-ID bit in a program file is set.

When does changing the process' effective user ID to be the owner of the file happen, **before** or **after** the kernel decides that the process can execute the file via the file access test?

- If "before", since the process' effective user ID is changed to be the owner of the file first, doesn't the kernel always decide that the process can execute the file via the file access test?
- If "after", since the kernel decides that the process can execute the file via the file access test, the process must have the effective ID matching the file's owner and the file also has the permission bit set. Then why is there a need to still change the effective user ID of the process to be the owner of the file?

Thanks.

Comment: If your "after" assumption would be correct, how would you run programs *not* owned by yourself? Or in other words: file permissions define who is allowed to run a program, setuid defines under which uid it runs under.

Comment: If "after", then  the kernel already decides that the process can execute the file via the file access test, so we can deduce that the process must have the effective ID matching the file's owner and the file also has the permission bit set.

Comment: No. A file can be owned by root but you still can execute it if the access rights are r-xr-xr-x for instance.

Comment: Then why is there a need to change the effective id of the process to be the owner of the file? Assume that you believe "after" is correct.

Comment: Tim, are you possibly thinking that the kernel code that does the access check is running with whatever limited permissions the user-mode process that called `execve` has? That is not the case; a kernel-mode process has permissions equal to or exceeding that of user-mode root, no matter what uid the user process is.

Comment: Tim, because the new process needs to write to a file the user itself doesn‘t. For instance if you want to change your password (which requires an update of `/etc/passwd`.