# Is it ever meaningful that the owner of an executable file doesn't have the execution permission?

Tags: permissions, executable, setuid

1. Assume an executable file has its set-user-id bit on.

   When a process executes the executable file, it changes its
   effective user ID  to  the owner user ID of the executable file, **after** the kernel decides that the file can be executed via file
   access test. See
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456225/how-and-when-does-exec-change-the-effective-user-id-when-the-set-user-id-is-s
   and 
   [What is the usage of set-user-ID of a program file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440060/what-is-the-usage-of-set-user-id-of-a-program-file)

   Does that means that the owner user ID of the executable file  can
   be one which doesn't pass the file access test performed by the
   kernel, even if the test has already been passed based on the
   original effective user ID of the process ?
2. Generally speaking, is it ever meaningful that the owner of an
   executable file doesn't have the execution permission?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe relevant: [Difference between Real User ID, Effective User ID and Saved User ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455684/difference-between-real-user-id-effective-user-id-and-saved-user-id)

Comment: Are you enabling the SUID bit on your own executables or something? On my system, I have exactly 16 executables that have the SUID bit set, and they all have to do with very specific system administration tasks (changing passwords, shutting down, changing to another user etc.).  What is the practical application that requires you to set/modify the SUID bit?

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't have any except for learning purpose. Thanks for letting me know. I found 22 by `find /usr/bin -perm /6000 | wc -l` and `find /bin -perm /6000 | wc -l` thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180868/674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I have no idea how that works for certain (largely because I've never seen any use for such a configuration).  My guess would be that it doesn't matter, because SUID effectively puts a `seteuid()` call at the very end of the startup process (right before executions transfers to the program itself), which would be *after* the file gets loaded for execution, and therefore once the check has happened as well (the check happens (at least on Linux) prior to any data being loaded into memory).
2. That depends on what you mean by meaningful.  It functionally does nothing, since the owner can just set the executable bit themselves (assuming no extra mandatory-access-controls that prevent them from doing so), so in that respect not really.  As far as whether it's meaningful in the sense of being useful, I can't come up with any situations where it would make sense for the owner to not have execute permissions but other users do, so I would say no there as well.